# Multidimensional-array in Ceylon

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, ceylon

I would like to work in Ceylon with a multidimensional array. Is this planned in Ceylon? If so, how can I declare it?

I would like to use this construct in Ceylon, as shown here in Java:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 5;

String[][] myStringArray = new String [x][y];

myStringArray[2][2] = "a string";
```

Answer (score 3):

First, consider whether you really need an array (i.e. something with fixed length and modifiable elements), or whether a list (or list of lists) or a map might be better. Though from your example, you seem to need modification.

In the JVM, a "multidimensional" array is just an array of arrays.

In Java, `new String[y]` creates an array filled with `null` entries, which is not an allowed value of type `String` in Ceylon. So you can either have an array of `String?` (which allows `null`), or pre-fill your array with some other value, using e.g. [Array.ofSize(...)](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Array.type.html#ofSize):

```ceylon
Array.ofSize(y, "hello")
```

The same is valid for arrays of arrays. We could do this:

```ceylon
value myStringArray = Array.ofSize(x, Array.ofSize(y, "hello"));
```

Though this would have the same array in each "row" of the 2D-array, which is not what we want (as replacing `myStringArray[2][2]` would replace all entries with a 2 as the second coordinate). Here the other Array constructor is useful, which takes an iterable:

```ceylon
value myStringArray = Array({ Array.ofSize(y, "hello") }.repeat(x));
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the iterable enumeration evaluates its arguments lazily, and thus the array constructor will get x different elements.

Answer (score 1):

I like Paulo's answer, but here's an alternative approach, which allows us to use a comprehension to populate the 2D array:

```
//the size of the square 2D array
value n = 5;

//create it using a nested comprehension
value arr = Array { 
    for (i in 1..n-1) Array { 
        for (j in 0..n-1) 
            i==j then 1 else 0 
    }
};

//display it
for (row in arr) {
    printAll(row);
}
```